# How to display field values after redirect to same page in html?

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I have an HTML page for a search operation.

Once the user enters the search criteria and clicks the search button, the result of the search should be displayed on the same page.

However, on the search results page, the search field values entered by the user are cleared due to refresh/redirect to the same page.

How do I capture the field values and display them?

Comment: please specify tags in your question

Comment: General HTML tags only.Using struts 1.x, In jsp page i'm writing html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I think, would be to merge your search form and results page, and have your form submit to itself like so:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

this way you can still access the searched item by using the form submission your search uses, and making the `value=""` attribute of the search field the same value; in PHP this would be:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $_GET["search"]; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

---

If you do still want to have an intermediate page, then use a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="searched"/>
```

if you have users submit a form to be redirected.

Comment: Search fields are clearing when the page is refreshed/redirected to the same page.

Comment: You mean submitted using `<form action=""></form>` to the same page?

Comment: No.. Submitted form with action="login" it will be trapped by struts controller and forward it to same page when login failed...

Comment: It would be easiest to just use the same page for both login code and the actual login form, so that you can get what the user typed in. Or if you are using GET you could redirect to the form, submitting via GETwith a .

Comment: Some thing like redirecting to `form.jsp?lastsearch=redpumpkin` so you can access the search terms from the `lastsearch` GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to get the value pairs from your search form using GET string variables. You would access the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object property, where [`.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) will give you the query string (`GET` URL segment), if there is one.

For instance:

```
<form method="get">
<p>
<input type="text" name="q1" value="Search Criteria 1">
<input type="text" name="q2" value="Search Criteria 2">
<input type="text" name="q3" value="Search Criteria 3">
<button type="submit">Submit Search</button>
</p>
</form>
```

We could try the following to see what is in the `GET` URL, if anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var getpairs = location.search.substring(1).split('&'),
        pairs = {},
        i = getpairs.length,
        pair;

    while (i--) {
        pair = getpairs[i].split('=');
        pairs[pair[0]] = decodeURI(pair[1]) || true;
    }

    if (pairs.length) {
        console.log(pairs);
    } else {
        console.log('Nothing in GET string.');
    }
})();
</script>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/get.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this

```
<input type="text" name="bar" value="${param.bar}">
```